# Postgrespro : pg_probackup : error while executing add instance for pg_probackup

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I have used pg_basebackup  and now experimenting with postgres using pg_probackup
I am following documentation present on  https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/10/app-pgprobackup

I am able to execute following commands on setup:

- pg_probackup-13 version
- pg_probackup-13 init -B /root/myProBackup/

but having issue while adding DB instance:
Command:

```
pg_probackup-13 add-instance -B /root/myProBackup/ --instance=db1  --pgdata=/var/lib/pgpro/std-13/data
```

> ERROR: *Calculated CRC checksum does not match value stored in file.
> Either the file is corrupt, or it has a different layout than this program
> is expecting. The results below are untrustworthy.*

Can anyone tell me how to add instance properly and take proper `pg_probackup`?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution, if you use pg_probackup std for vanilla postgres it won't work, you need to use pg_probackup for vanilla here is the repository where you need to download the desired version. before installation, you need to uninstall the previous version of pg_probackup.

http://repo.postgrespro.ru/pg_probackup/deb/pool/

after installing the vanilla version you will need to initialize the backup directory again and after that the instance will be successfully initialized